# Is there a unique ID available for modifiers?

Tags: maxscript

I'm trying to wrangle some WHEN callbacks from attached nodes via the optional id attribute in a modifier script.

If I set it to something arbitrary then it works well enough in most cases, however, if I have the same node specified by 2 different instances of the modifier, it addresses the callbacks from both instances, that is a problem.

This would easily be solved if I could have a modifier instance specific ID of the modifier or its delegate, sorta like object.handle on objects.

Since maxscript documentation is the way it is, I haven't been able to find anything. Does anybody have a clue as to where I could get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [animHandle](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/16/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-25211F97-E81A-4D49-AFB6-50B30894FBEB.htm), you can get it using the `GetHandleByAnim` function.